# React Native ListView renderRow async

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native

I'm trying to get a ListView to work with items that also have to get a thumbnail for each item, I've tried a couple of tries but I don't seem to get it working. here is an example of the code:

```
renderRow(rowData,sectionID,rowID){
    base.child(`${rowID}/avatar`)
      .once('value',(snapshot)=>{
        let avatars = this.state.avatars;
        avatars[rowID] = {uri: snapshot.val()};
        this.setState({
          avatars : avatars
        });
      },(err)=>{console.log(err)});
    return (
      <View>
          <Image source={this.state.avatars[rowID]} />
          <Text >{rowData.screenName}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

So the problem is to render the listview item when the image is ready. I''ve tried also to return the component after the firebase call has returned but I get the error:

> Must return a valid component

```
base.child(`users/${rowData.userId}/attrs/avatar`)
   .once('value',(snapshot)=>{
     let avatar;
     if(snapshot.val() == null){
       avatar = require('../assets/images/avatar.png');
     }else{
       avatar = {uri: snapshot.val()};
     }
  return (
   <View>
       <Image source={this.state.avatars[rowID]} />
       <Text>{rowData.content}</Text>
   </View>
  )
   },(err)=>{console.log(err)});
```

There might be some syntax errors. I just striped the code for the unnecessary details. But I guess this gives an idea of what I want to accomplish.

Comment: I have the same problem for a while now. Did you find a solution or even a helpful site? Thanks @Diogo Barroso

Comment: I'm too having trouble with this. Would love to see your solution @Diogo